# Запрет предзагрузки страницы

Tags: html

Многие современные браузеры имеют функцию предзагрузки страниц, чтобы ускорить переход на эти страницы.
Имеются ли в html средства, чтобы запретить такое поведение для всей страницы или отдельной ссылки на странице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Предзагрузка не имеет отношения к самому HTML, это просто фича браузеров. Чтобы предзагрузка не выполнялась, адрес должен отсутствовать, иметь неправильный формат, находиться в "левом" атрибуте и т.п. Иначе парсер браузера его "увидит" и может попытаться произвести предзагрузку. Можно указанными выше способами "спрятать" адрес и вписывать его в нужное время и в нужное место скриптом.

W3C описывает *resource hint link* [prefetch](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#dfn-prefetch) и [prerender](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#dfn-prerender), которые выдают браузеру рекомендацию о предзагрузке содержимого и даже пререндеренге страницы соответственно. Но это во-первых является лишь *рекомендацией*, а во-вторых, обратной операции, то есть явного запрета, стандарт не имеет.

Comment: Насчет отношения к хтмл могу вспомнить про: noindex, nofollow. Подумал, что возможно уже есть у хтмл средства и для такой функции браузеров.

Comment: @ReinRaus Есть. Но однонаправленные: https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#dfn-prefetch. Рекомендация есть, но запрета нет. Современные браузеры и без prefetch по ссылкам лазят.

Comment: Рекомендация в3ц- уже неплохо. Может когда-нибудь появится поддержка от браузеров. Перенесите, пожалуйста, про рекомендацию в ответ.

Comment: @ReinRaus Добавил.